# ¿Cómo solucionar esto? Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received

Tags: html, chrome, depuración

Hoy he abierto Chrome para trabajar en una página que estoy haciendo y en la consola me aparece este mensaje.

```
0.html:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Mas o menos dice que...

```
No comprobado el último error en tiempo de ejecución: El puerto del mensaje se cerró antes de recibir la respuesta.
```

Ayer no me aperecia este mensaje, así que he creado **0.html** que es un documento en blanco (sin código) y sigue apareciendo este mensaje, así que creo que debe ser un problema del navegador o algo asi.

¿Alguien sabe que és o mejor aún cómo hacer para que no aperezca?

¿Este error va a afectar en la depuración de la página?

Comment: verifica las extensiones puede que alguna esté no resolviendo un `sendmessage` sin respuesta

Comment: Era eso exatamte!! Deshabilité las extensiones y el error desapareció. Muchas Gracias @aloMalbarez.

Comment: @aloMalbarez por favor publica tu comentario como respuesta para que el OP pueda aceptarla.

Comment: @IvánRodríguez por favor recuerda aceptar la respuesta una vez sea publicada, o puedes responder y aceptar tu propia respuesta. Saludos.

Comment: Ok, acabo de verla... me hubiese gustado que fuera la de AloMalvarez ya que fue el el primero en decirlo... pero bueno, vamos a darle un poco de vidilla a este nuevo usuario para que siga animado a seguir contestando preguntas. Necesitamos a mas gente así!! Saludos!!

Comment: En mi caso era la extencion de Norton

Comment: muchas gracias por sus respuestas en mi caso era: VPN Gratis para Chrome - Free VPN VeePN

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Desactivé algunas extensiones y lo solucioné, en mi caso es la extensión de IE Tab que no podía resolver y daba error.

Comment: Si, exacto, es por culpa de las extensiones. Gracias!!